# I need to select a table attribute based on a COUNT of a related attribute

Tags: sql, select, count, max

These are my tables:

```
   VENDOR:          PRODUCT:           ITEM:             STORE:
-  VENDOR_ID     -  PRODUCT_ID      -  ITEM_ID        -  STORE_ID
-  VENDOR_NAME   -  PRODUCT_DESC    -  STORE_ID       -  STORE_NAME
                 -  VENDOR_ID       -  PRODUCT_ID     -  STORE_LOCATION
                                    -  ITEM_PRICE
```

The vendor table is about the vendor of each product, the product table stores product information, and the item table stores information for each store about what products it has in its inventory. It holds a unique item_id for each product in the store. The store table has information about each store. I need to select the Store_ID that has the greatest number of different item_ids. I think it may be relatively straight forward, but I'm not sure how to go about it. All I need to do is find the STORE_ID that belongs to the store that has the greatest range of PRODUCTs in the inventory.

I'm using ACCESS SQL, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework question. I see so many users posting this...

Comment: Yeah, a homework question... That's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 store_id
FROM (
    SELECT store_id, count(item_id)
    FROM item
    GROUP BY store_id
    ORDER BY count(item_id) DESC
)
```

Be careful with the details here. I'm not sure from reading your question if you understand the difference between and item and a product. This query returns the store with the greatest number of items, which might not be the same as the store with the greatest number of products.